# ambiguity between two methods in c#

Tags: c#

```
public double BAL_insert()
{
    return dobj.DAL_insert(this);
}

public double DAL_insert(BAL_class bobj)
{
    con = cobj.tierconnection();
    con.Open();
    query = "insert into Employeeinandout values(@prm_Name)";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Name", bobj.name);
    double r = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    return r;
}
```

[getting ambiguous between these two methods. How can i solve it.]

Comment: Is these two methods in the same class? what is the class of dobj object?
Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
    public double DAL_insert(BAL_class bobj = null)
    {
       if(bobj == null)
       {
          bobj = this;
       }
       con = cobj.tierconnection();
       con.Open();
       query = "insert into Employeeinandout values(@prm_Name)";
       cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Name", bobj.name);
       double r = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();
       return r;
    }
```